# TypeError: value.forEach is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to modify a standard ERC20 token to send the same value to multiple addresses like so:

```
function transferToMultipleAccounts(address[] _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {

    for (uint i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
        transfer(_to[i], _value);
    }

    return true;
  }
```

I've gota truffle unit test for it:

```
let accountsToReceive = [accounts[6], accounts[7], accounts[8], accounts[9]]
      let txHash = await token.transferToMultipleAccounts(2, accountsToReceive)
```

but when I run the unit test I get this error:

```
 TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
```

If I remove the loop everything works fine, but when I put the loop back I get that error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order of your parameters. It should be:

```
let txHash = await token.transferToMultipleAccounts(accountsToReceive, 2)
```